# Compare dictionary with a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to compare a dictionary value with a variable but for some reasons I can't output the part that I want from the dictionary.
The dictionary is an ouput from a html table. 
This is the code that I use to prase the html table into a dictionary:

```
with open('output.csv') as fd:
    rd = csv.DictReader(fd, skipinitialspace=True)
    for row in rd:
        lista = { k: row[k] for k in row if k in ['Name', 'Clan Days']}
```

This is the output:

```
{'Name': 'SirFulgeruL2k19', 'Clan Days': '140'}
{'Name': 'Darius', 'Clan Days': '127'}
```

How to I compare for example the clan days from the first dictionary and if the value matches the value that I set in a variable should get the name as a string so I can later use it in another line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you first read the data into a list of dictionaries:

```
data = [{ k: row[k] for k in row if k in ['Name', 'Clan Days']}
        for row in rd]
```

You may use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to search for the first dictionary in `data` matching the `Clan Days` value defaulting to `None` if no entries matched your search query:

```
desired_clan_days = '140'
clan_name = next((entry["Name"] for entry in data 
                  if entry["Clan Days"] == desired_clan_days), None)
```

Now, `next()` would return you the first match, if you need all of the matches, just use a list comprehension:

```
clan_names = [entry["Name"] for entry in data 
              if entry["Clan Days"] == desired_clan_days]
```

---

Note that this kind of search requires you to, in the worst case (entry not found), loop through all the entries in `data`. If this kind of search is the primary use case of this data structure, consider re-designing it to better fit the problem - e.g. having clan_days value as a key with a list of clan names:

```
data = { 
    "140": ["SirFulgeruL2k19"],
    "127": ["Darius"]
}
```

In that state, getting a match would be a constant operation and as easy as `data[desired_clan_days]`. `defaultdict(list)` is something that would help you to make that transformation.

Comment: I tried adding the code that you suggested but for some reasons I get for the `desired_clan_days = '140'` line a syntax error.
`import csv
with open('output.csv') as fd:
    data = [{ k: row[k] for k in row if k in ['Name', 'Clan Days']}
        for row in fd
            desired_clan_days = '140'
            clan_names = [entry["Name"] for entry in data 
            if entry["Clan Days"] == desired_clan_days]`

Comment: @SirFulgeruL I think you forgot the closing `]` after the `for row in fd `

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what exactly you want, but if it's just comparing a dictionary value to a variable and getting the Name part if they match, you would get something like this..

```
>>> dict = {'Name': 'SirFulgeruL2k19', 'Clan Days': '140'}
>>> target = 140
>>> if int(dict['Clan Days']) == target:
...    name = dict['Name']
...    
>>> name
'SirFulgeruL2k19'
```

---

Edit: Read your post too quickly, considering it's all the rows from a HTML table this code is too simple. Use alecxe's answer :)